# make span tag show full background instead wrapping in responsive

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, responsive

In responsive `span` is not showing full background.

It shows proper up to 836 pixels after less than that it wraps in another line, I want that only wrap text not background.

How to show full background?

**Snippet**

```css
span{
  background: red;
  color: white;
  padding: 50px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: arial;
  font-size: 20px;
}
```

```html
<span>In responsive span is not showing full background. How to show full background?</span>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

set `inline-block` to `span`, because `span` is an inline element

```css
span{
  background: red;
  color: white;
  padding: 50px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: arial;
  font-size: 20px;
  display:inline-block
}
```

```html
<span>In responsive span is not showing full background. How to show full background?</span>
```